# D: Split string from the second occurrence of the character

Tags: string, split, d

I need to do splitting string before the second occurrence ("-").

Example: `s1-qwe-123`

need to get: `s1-qwe`

What is the best practice?

Ehm, thanks, but faced with situation where some files have structure like:
`s1-123`. And I need to get from them: `s1`.

Is there any way to make variant with split process such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split it and join it together again.

```
string line = "s1-qwe-123";
string interestedBit = line.split("-")[0..2].join("-");
```

Or a loop through the chars:

```
int idx;
bool found;
string line = "s1-qwe-123";
for(idx = 0; idx < line.length; ++idx){
    if(line[idx] == '-')
        if(found)
            break;
        else
            found = true;
}
auto interestedBit = line[0..idx];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int saw;
auto s = "s1-qwe-123".findSplitBefore!(c => c == '-' && saw++ > 0)[0];
```

Comment: Nice use of post-increment! I was trying to think of a nice way to do that but just resorted to a loop. Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

My original answer was completely wrong as I misread the question. Here is a correct answer that provides a slight variation on the `split` solution already suggested in other answers:

```
import std.algorithm : splitter; 
import std.array : join;
import std.range : take;
auto res = "s1-qwe-123".splitter("-").take(2).join('-');
assert(res == "s1-qwe");
```

The advantage of using `splitter` over `split` is lazy evaluation. This should only walk up to the second '-' and no further.

Comment: Oops, it looks like my anwser was wrong anyways. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, I'll present two.

The first would be to split the whole string by "-" and then to join the first two elements:

```
import std.stdio, std.string;
"s1-qwe-123".split("-")[0 .. 2]
            .join("-")
            .writeln;    // -> "s1-qwe"
```

This is simple but may not be efficient enough as the whole string has to be read. The other method I would propose is to use regular expressions as there is a matchFirst function that reads the string only up to the first occurence of the expression.

```
import std.stdio, std.regex;
"s1-qwe-123".matchFirst("[^-]+-[^-]+")[0]
            .writeln;  // -> "s1-qwe"
```

And if you want it to be *really* fast you can use a compile-time regular expression:

```
import std.stdio, std.regex;
"s1-qwe-123".matchFirst(ctRegex!("[^-]+-[^-]+"))[0]
            .writeln;  // -> "s1-qwe"
```